# C++ pass by reference then set a pointer to the object

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, pass-by-reference

I am creating a class LinkedList. I am having difficulty adding another node to my list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    T element;
    T *next;

public:    
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(T element);

    void add(LinkedList<T> &otherList);
    void print();
};

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    next = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(T element)
{
    this->element = element;
    next = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::add(LinkedList<T> &otherList)
{
    next = &otherList;
}


template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::print()
{
    LinkedList<T> *current = this;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << current->element;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int main()
{    
    LinkedList<std::string> myFirst("First");
    LinkedList<std::string> mySecond("Second");    
    myFirst.add(mySecond);
    myFirst.print();    

    return 0;
}
```

This works however if I make the change:

```
void add(const LinkedList<T> &otherList);

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::add(const LinkedList<T> &otherList)
{
    next = &otherList; //now an error right here
}
```

Then I get an error stating:

```
Assigning to 'LinkedList<std::__1::basic_string<char> > *' from incompatible type 'const LinkedList<std::__1::basic_string<char> > *'
```

Why is it I get this error?

Comment: Can you show *how* you call the function? Including declarations of involved variables.

Comment: you're trying to assign a pointer to a constant to a simple pointer. Make your "next" a pointer to a constant (i.e. const LinkedList *).

Comment: @DanKruchinin Additionally to the `const` problem, the types simply don't match.

Comment: Thank you for the response, adding const worked perfectly. It makes sense now

Comment: @user906357: It is clear from your comment that you still have not understood it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`next` is a `T*`, and you're trying to assign a `const LinkedList<T>*` to it.

I suppose you meant something like `next = &(otherList.element)` (though even then I think your list semantics are somewhat broken — elements shouldn't typically be *shared* by multiple containers unless you're very, very clear about the ownership semantics).

Contrary to your claims, [your first program doesn't work either](http://ideone.com/iV0f4a) for the same reason.

Comment: The first program did run in Xcode, it displayed FirstSecond as desired

Comment: @user906357: Then either you didn't run the code you thought you were running, or Xcode is _very_ broken.

Comment: ah, the difference was element and next were public, when private you are correct

Comment: @user906357: The access modifiers have nothing to do with it. The two types are fundamentally incompatible.

Comment: I just meant that I was not running the code I thought I was in the first program. The difference was they were public and not private. But it still runs in Xcode when they are private.